# invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript

Tags: c++, arrays

help me please as soon as possible. I am doing a special program, but I can't fully understand which exact way do pointers behave here. Help me so solve that error:

> error: invalid types ‘int[int]’ for array subscript
>   if((friendsOnPhoto[j][1]>tempH) && (&friendsOnPhoto[j][1]!=&friendsAmount[i][1]))

The code is:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

int friendsAmount;
int i=0, j=0;
int tempW=0;
int tempH=0;
cin>>friendsAmount;
int** friendsOnPhoto = new int* [friendsAmount];

for (i=0;i<2;i++)
*friendsOnPhoto = new int [i];

for (i=0;i<friendsAmount;i++)
{
cin>>friendsOnPhoto[i][0];
tempW += friendsOnPhoto[i][0];
cin>>friendsOnPhoto[i][1];
}

for (int i=0;i<friendsAmount;i++){ 
for (int j=0;j<friendsAmount;j++){
if((*friendsOnPhoto[j][1]>tempH) && (*friendsOnPhoto[j][1]!=*friendsAmount[i][1]))
tempH = friendsOnPhoto[i][1];
}
}
cout<<(tempW-friendsOnPhoto[i][0])*tempH;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, get rid of all the `*` in

```
if((*friendsOnPhoto[j][1]>tempH) && (*friendsOnPhoto[j][1]!=*friendsAmount[i][1]))
```

These are not pointers here, but plain simple `int` elements.

Secondly,

```
(*friendsOnPhoto[j][1] != *friendsAmount[i][1])
                           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

This is wrong, as you have declared `friendsAmount` as

```
int friendsAmount;
```

Hence, your code should be:

```
if((friendsOnPhoto[j][1]>tempH) && (friendsOnPhoto[j][1]!=friendsAmount))
```

Answer (score 0):

The statement

```
*friendsOnPhoto = new int [i];
```

overwrite the same location, `friendsOnPhoto[0]`. The number of `int` elements also differs depending on the loop index, first you allocate *zero* elements, and the next iteration you allocate one. And then your loop is over.

Since you only initialize `friendsOnPhoto[0]`, any other index will be using uninitialized memory and lead to [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

I'm sure you must mean e.g.

```
for (i=0;i<friendsAmount;i++)
    friendsOnPhoto[i] = new int [2];
```